# Does thread safety remarks on methods cover properties as well?

Tags: c#, msdn

I'm pretty new to writing C#, but I've come to understand that Properties are just syntactic sugar for writing getters and setters. So when the documentation states

*Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.*

would it be correct to assume that this applies to properties as well? I.e. any static property would be guaranteed to be thread safe but not instance properties.

Comment: 'members' is wider than methods; besides, properies are accessed through accessor/getter methods; so there is no real difference

Comment: Oh my, I completely missed that it said "members", not "methods". How embarassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member includes properties, fields and methods.  So yes, a static member of the type if declared as such is threadsafe.  As a property is a member, the static properties are threadsafe.

@Sehe has caught me on Events are also "members".  Not sure what a threadsafe event would do though ;)

Comment: You are forgetting events. These too